# Cross filtering in viz plugin

Tags: apache-superset

I need to create a custom viz plugin in apache-superset. It needs to send cross filters data to other viz in the same dashboard.

So I created a time-series plugin using [this tutorial](https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/creating-viz-plugins). I then added the the `emitFilterControl` (from `@superset-ui/chart-controls`) in my plugin `controlPanel.ts`. I know have the 'Enable dashboard cross filters' checkbox in my viz settings menu.

Now, I need to implement filter emission in my plugin code. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any docs relating to this. I also looked through `superset/superset-frontend` source code but it was not successful either. Has anyone implemented such a feature ?

Thanks in advance

I enabled these flags in `superset/config.py`:

```py
FEATURE_FLAGS: Dict[str, bool] = {
    "DASHBOARD_CROSS_FILTERS": True,
    "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS": True,
    "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET": True,
    "DASHBOARD_FILTERS_EXPERIMENTAL": True,
}
```